# python passing variable to function issue

Tags: python

I am new to python, but it works in different languages.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import netaddr
print(sys.argv[1])
cidrs = netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs(sys.argv[1])
print cidrs
```

output:

```
./script.py \"223.252.0.0\",\"223.252.127.255\"
"223.252.0.0","223.252.127.255"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script.py", line 7, in <module>
    cidrs = netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs(sys.argv[1])
TypeError: iprange_to_cidrs() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Did you bother to read [the documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/api.html#netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs)?

Comment: Yes, I did. But the question is not related to netaddr

Comment: Yes it is, because the documentation shows that you need to pass two arguments to that function, and you're only passing one.

Comment: but i pass "223.252.0.0","223.252.127.255". it just do not receive the content of variable sys.argv[1]

Comment: Yes.  That is one string with a comma in the middle.  If you want to pass two things, accept two arguments on the command line and pass those.

Comment: Putting a comma in between two strings doesn't magically make it two arguments.

Comment: cidrs = netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs("sys.argv[1]","sys.argv[2]") netaddr.core.AddrFormatError: failed to detect IP version: 'sys.argv[1]'

Comment: `cidrs = netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs("sys.argv[1]","sys.argv[2]")` != `cidrs = netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs("\"223.252.0.0\",\"223.252.127.255\"")`

Comment: @user2079197: You need to read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to get a grip on the basics of Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you really insist on having a single command-line argument containing a comma,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import netaddr
input = sys.argv[1].split(",")
print("%r" % input)
cidrs = netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs(*input)
print cidrs
```

This creates a Python list of two strings out of the single string that is `sys.argv[1]` and passes that to `iprange_to_cidrs`.  This only works if there is exactly one comma in the first argument.  My recommendation would be to use

```
cidrs = netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

like others have already convingcingly argued.